# Running FREngine on Linux VM machine

Tags: java, ubuntu, finereader

I have installed FREngine 12 version. 
The license was installed.

I have exported JDK variable and run the command:

```
echo "/opt/ABBYY/FREngine12/Bin" | sudo tee -a /etc/ld.so.conf; sudo ldconfig
```

But during initializing `Engine` this way:

```
Engine.InitializeEngine(
    engineConfig.getDllFolder(), engineConfig.getCustomerProjectId(),
    engineConfig.getLicensePath(), engineConfig.getLicensePassword(), "", "", false);
```

I receive an error:

> Cannot load DLL /opt/ABBYY/FREngine12/Bin/libFREngine.so.
>     Unknown error. Error code: 0x0
>
> Please, be aware that this file exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found the solution. I had to install g++ compiler. Hope it will help someone.

Answer (score 0):

You're running the commands as sudo, but my guess is that are you not exporting the environment variables as sudo

Comment: How I can export vars as sudo?

Comment: @UladzislauKaminski: Create a script with your env variables and your app startup routine, then run this script as sudo